# I want to select a specific data, but query result gives all column in sqlite

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have a little problem. I am beginner on database.

I want to select Country_Code from table2, using Country_Name column from table 1.

```
SELECT Country_Code FROM COUNTRIES, COUNTRY_SMALL_INFO WHERE COUNTRIES.Country_Name = 'Belgium'
```

I tried to get only country code of Belgium, but I got all Country_Code column.

This is the result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6sFRu.png

Comment: Post your tables structures please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should bind COUNTRIES with COUNTRY_SMALL_INFO somehow. Maybe they have id columns? If so your query could be

```
SELECT Country_Code 
FROM COUNTRIES, COUNTRY_SMALL_INFO 
WHERE COUNTRIES.ID = COUNTRY_SMALL_INFO.ID AND COUNTRIES.Country_Name = 'Belgium'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to `JOIN` both tables, so it is doing a cartesian product. Also use `DISTINCT` to have unique set of `country_code`. Try something like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.Country_Code 
  FROM COUNTRIES c 
    INNER JOIN COUNTRY_SMALL_INFO i ON c.id = i.country_id
    WHERE c.Country_Name = 'Belgium'
```